# How do I fix a problem with a function that is supposed to only move 0's to the end of the list, but moves False values as well?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm writing a function to move 0's to the end of a list, but when a False value is in the list, it converts it to 0 and moves it to the end as well.

I've tried many variations of if statements including:

1. if i == 0
2. if type(i) != bool and i == 0
3. if str(i) == '0'

```
def move_zeros(array):
    for i in array:
        if str(i) == '0' and str(i) != 'False':
            array.remove(i)
            array.append(0)
    return array
```

In case of `[0,1,None,2,False,1,0]`, I expected the function to return `[1,None,2,False,1,0,0]`, but it returned `[1,None,2,1,0,0,0]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of gotchas here. One that you already understood is that there is not trivial way to discriminate between `0` and `False`. However, there are two other points:

1. Modifying an iterable (list, dict, etc.) that you are iterating over is dangerous. You should avoid doing that (unless you cannot do otherwise, e.g. with very large amounts of data that you cannot afford to copy in memory).
2. `array.remove()` does not do what you think it does. It [removes from `array` the first element that is `==` to its argument](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), which may or may not be in the same position as the element in the iteration loop. That is responsible for transforming your `False` into a `0`.

With that in mind, here's a working version:

```
def is_integer_zero(x):
    # The cleanest way I found, but you could argue for other options
    return x == 0 and not isinstance(x, bool)

def move_zeros(array):
    left_part = []
    right_part = []

    for i in array:
        if is_integer_zero(i):
            right_part.append(i)
        else:
            left_part.append(i)

    return left_part + right_part


l = [0, 1, None, 2, False, 1, 0]

print(move_zeros(l))  # [1, None, 2, False, 1, 0, 0]
```

`right_part` consists entirely of zeroes, so you could simplify the code / improve performance quite a bit, but that version has the advantage that you can use other conditions to choose what to right-shift.

Comment: if you want to make it more generic, consider passing the predicate function (here `is_integer_zero`) as a callback. Totally over the top for the OP's problem obviously but since you mentionned "using other conditions"... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues here. First, in Python, `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `False == 0`, so to tell apart `0` from `False` you have to test on your object's type. Also, modifying a list in place while iterating over it is a sure recipe for "off" errors.

Here's a plain stupid simple implementation that works:

```
def move_zeros(seq):
    head, tail = [], []
    for v in seq:
        if isinstance(v, int) and not isinstance(v, bool) and v == 0:
            tail.append(v)
        else:
            head.append(v)
    return head + tail
```

Comment: Thank you, I also added or isinstance(v,float) for possible 0.0 values

Comment: glad I could help - and feel free to upvote my answer then. You may also want to upvote and accept leporello's answer which is more accurate than mine

Comment: I'm pretty new to stack, literally signed up an hour ago so I upvoted both yours and leporello's answer but i think it won't show when i have less than 15 reputation

Comment: @hubvoy thanks for both of us 8-) - and please do not forget to _accept_  leporello's answer which deserves to be marked as the one correct answer here (remember that SO is about building a technical knowledge base so accepting the best solution is important for future readers).

Comment: ok accepting the answer is just ticking the thingy under the vote counter right?